# python websocket client connected status - how to update so I get correct status?

Tags: python, node.js, websocket

I am able to connect to a node.js [websocket](http://einaros.github.io/ws/) server using [python websocket](https://github.com/liris/websocket-client). When I ask the python websocket client if it is connected to the server, it is not accurate.

Here is what happens:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36)
>>> import websocket
>>> ws = websocket.WebSocket()
>>> ws.connect("ws://localhost:8081") # my websocket server is running, so all good here.
>>> ws.connected
True      # This is correct. Now I kill the websocker server
>>> ws.connected
True      # this should be false since the server is dead.
```

The [ws](http://einaros.github.io/ws/) node.js module comes with `wscat` and you can run a websocket server by the command `wscat -l 8081`.

How do I get an accurate status that indicates the true connected/disconnected state?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `.connected` attribute is not updated, unless `close` or `shutdown`, ... called, or `recv*` receive empty data.

Try to call `recv()`, then check the `.connected` attribute.